# Angularjs bootstrap popover blink after model change

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-popover

I am using angularjs [bootstrap popover](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/popover) inside a table.

The table is populated using ng-repeat and if the popover is open and i get new data to the table there is a flicker to the popover.

Here is a working example
[Pknkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/xVuU99rweiCTUXeUm4Vb)

Any thought on how can i prevent the flicker ?

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="ui.bootstrap.demo">
  <head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-2.0.0.js"></script>
    <script src="example.js"></script>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>

<div ng-controller="PopoverDemoCtrl">
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <table>
    <tr ng-repeat="item in list">
      <td>
        <button uib-popover-template="dynamicPopover.templateUrl" 
                popover-is-open="aux.openPopOverId==item.id" 
                ng-click="aux.openPopOverId=item.id" popover-placement="right" type="button" class="btn btn-link">
          Popover
        </button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

    <script type="text/ng-template" id="myPopoverTemplate.html">
        <div>{{dynamicPopover.content}}</div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Popup Title:</label>
          <input type="text" ng-model="dynamicPopover.title" class="form-control">
        </div>
    </script>
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And the js

```
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap']);
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('PopoverDemoCtrl', function ($scope,$interval, $sce) {
  $scope.dynamicPopover = {
    templateUrl: 'myPopoverTemplate.html',
    title: 'Title'
  };

  $scope.list = [{'id':1},{'id':2},{'id':3}];
  $scope.aux = {'openPopOverId':2};

  $scope.updateList = function(){
    $scope.list = [{'id':1},{'id':2},{'id':3}];
  }

  $interval($scope.updateList,500,0);
});
```

Comment: flicker has happens due to this : $interval($scope.updateList,500,0); may I know in detail what you want to do with this interval ?

Comment: the interval is needed, it update the table data from server

Comment: ok and you want to update data within every 5 seconds..

Comment: suppose there is new data inserted in table and what should be result there

Comment: i want to update data every X seconds, the low interval is just so that you see the porblem

Comment: I just updated ng-repeat with track option and rewrite to <tr ng-repeat="item in list"> to <tr ng-repeat="item in list track by item.id"> and its working please check and let me know if its working ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought this could be help you please [read here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) in detail..

[image]